# Como ajustar altura da div conforme o texto?

Tags: html, css

Criei uma div com largura definida, porém quando insiro uma palavra muito grande o texto continua saindo da div, como fazer para palavra continuar na linha de baixo?

Comment: só e você não definir a altura da div
ou usar o overflow hiden

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

nessa div.

Comment: +1 funciona perfeitamente no Firefox e Chrome. Alguém poderia verificar a compatibilidade no IE? Fiz um exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/tBNyz/

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente no ie7, ie8, ie9, e ie10 :) @utluiz

Comment: @PauloRoberto Obrigado!

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=word-wrap. Esse site é muito  bom para verificar a compatibilidade.

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver isso eu sempre faço uso da propriedade `float:`.

Por exemplo:

```
.minhaDiv { float:left; width:200px; }
```

Toda vez que o seu texto chegar perto do tamanho dessa `div`, ela irá "quebrar" para a linha de baixo.

Comment: Isso não funciona se tiver uma palavra maior que a div.