# Como eu faço para que a altura da minha div se ajuste com o tamanho do meu texto?

Tags: php, css

Quando eu insiro o meu texto ele ultrapassa a minha div.
Por favor me ajudem.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como ajustar altura da div conforme o texto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5302/como-ajustar-altura-da-div-conforme-o-texto)

Answer (score 3):

Substitua o `height` da `div` por `min-height`, desse modo, a
 altura da `div` será uma altura mínima, podendo ser expandida pelo texto, adicione também a classe `word-wrap: break-word;` à tag `<p>` para que o texto digitado nela quebre de linha ao chegar no `width` limite do elemento em que ela se encontra, no caso, sua `div`.
Observe:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#input").keyup(() => {
      var valInput = $('#input').val();
     $("#pTexto").text(valInput);
  });
});
```

```css
.texto{
  width:200px;
  min-height: 20px;
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff; 
}
p{
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="digite o texto aqui">
    <div class="texto">
      <p id="pTexto"></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```